# How to show ping and fps on screen

Tags: blade-and-soul

I am worried about performance.

even if it seems that everything is ok sometimes, I feel my character unresponsive or slow ,

Sometimes I experience a short "hop" between animations that could be because of latency or just that animation,
My PC specs are more tan capable to move the game grafics but I would like to have the options to visualice this information so I can adapt the settings or sigh at my slow network

EDIT: I have searched in the options menú and haven't spoted anything similar. like in WoW, Guild Wars 2 or league of legends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game engine is simply not intended for MMORPG. In a type of bad optimization this game will not work smoothly even at the most powerful PC. And, alas, developers don't plan to change anything in the kernel of the engine.

To display 'FPS' on the screen, you should check checkbox in settings. First tab, show FPS item.
The 'Ping' display on the screen at the moment (3/18/2016) is only announced on the Korean server, and it is unknown when this feature is put into game. Up to this point you can use the free utility called PGUI which was written by the fan of game. You can find her [here](http://www.bladeandsouldojo.com/topic/148575-pgui-release-2540-all-regions-upk-viewer/).

Comment: I baffles me that still today they bring out these things, for now you are the closest to what i expected as an answer, will then wait for the ping update and try to enjoy the game, still didn't saw the option

Comment: Wow, I have already been wondering why the game's performance sucks so bad, even though my PC is really decent (Always playing FFXIV with highest graphics and constantly at 60 fps)

Answer (score 1):

You can check your ping by using Task Manager->Performance->Open Resource Monitor->Network

Check out the game in the "Processes with Network Activity" and you will be able to see the Latency (ping) in the "TCP Connections".

A guide with screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYbgj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use https://camwebapp.com/

It's NZXT's computer monitoring program. It displays not just your computer performance but also your games performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graphics card on your computer then I'm sure it came with some software for you to install on your computer. All you have to do is open the software and check the option to view fps on screen while playing. For example I use geforce gtx 970, it came with a software that lets me edit the performance to my liking, it recommends me the best based on my specs and does much more. Hope this helped.

Comment: This solves the FPS problema, but ping? think that mayby i have a constant 60 prefect FPS with no variation but I dont really know if i am having an above average lag or a lag spike, hence the ping AND fps

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to show your ping on your monitor constantly as you do with fps but i can tell  you that you can get to see your ping if you follow these steps while on game. (If you have two monitors i would just put this on the other monitor that way you can see your ping live)  Hope this helped.  http://imgur.com/a/OvHdw